# Остановка (пауза) видео YouTube

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, youtube, youtube-api

Есть модальное окно на CSS, в нём — карусель видео с YouTube.
Используется [Blueimp Gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery). При закрытии модального окна воспроизведение продолжается.

Есть ли возможность остановки всех или текущего видео, не зная его ID? Догадываюсь, что это делается средствами YouTube Player API, типа `player.pauseVideo():Void`, но как его правильно использовать? Куда сунуть и где взять ID текущего видео?

**UPD**: есть вот такие данные из описания:

```
var youTubeOptions = {
    // The list object property (or data attribute) with the YouTube video id:
    youTubeVideoIdProperty: 'youtube',
    // Optional object with parameters passed to the YouTube video player:
    // h t t p s ://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
    youTubePlayerVars: undefined,
    // Require a click on the native YouTube player for the initial playback:
    youTubeClickToPlay: true
};    

----------    

blueimp.Gallery([
    {
        title: 'A YouYube video',
        href: 'h t t p s://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID',
        type: 'text/html',
        youtube: 'VIDEO_ID',
        poster: 'h t t p s://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/maxresdefault.jpg'
    },
    {
        title: 'Banana',
        href: 'h t t p s://example.org/images/banana.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        thumbnail: 'h t t p s://example.org/thumbnails/banana.jpg'
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

**РЕШЕНО!**
при условии что API youtube включены.

Небольшая функция с использованием JQuery останавливающая любые видео во фреймах.
Подходит для автоматической остановки видео во фрэйме при закрытии пользователем модального окна.

```
<!-- HTML -->

<body>
...
<div id="close_vid">
   <img src="img/closem.png"/>
</div>
...
</body>
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#close_vid', function(){
   jQuery("iframe").each(function() {
      jQuery(this)[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*')});
});
```

[Вот рабочий пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ciberpol/eo6L6g28/6/)

При этом видео нужно передать гет-параметр ?enablejsapi=1:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4fce6nKsjXo?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```